# Delete Messages from a Topic in Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

So I am new to working with Apache Kafka and I am trying to create a simple app so I can try to understand the API better. I know this question has been asked a lot here, but how can I clear out the messages/records that are stored on a topic?

Most of the answers I have seen say to change the message retention time or to delete & recreate the topic. Neither of these are options for me as I do not have access to the server.properties file. I am not running Kafka locally, it is hosted on a server. Is there a way to do do it in Java code maybe or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are searching for a way to delete messages selectively, the new AdminClient API (usable from Java code) provides the following `deleteRecords` method :

https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html

Comment: I used AdminUtils instead to just delete the topic if it already existed and recreate it. Not exactly the best solution but I was having issues using the AdminClient you mentioned as I only had the method deleteRecordsBefore() which I was not exactly sure what to do with.

Comment: If you are using the deleteRecordsBefore() you are using the old Scala client in AdminUtils while the suggested way in the newer versions is to use the new AdminClient API which is in Java. You have a deleteRecords method which provides you a way for deleting all messages whose offset is smaller than the given offset.

Comment: You are right. I was using apparently the wrong AdminClient which is why I could not find the method to begin with and hence resorted to using AdminUtils. I had pulled in the wrong import statement from my IDE without realizing it, kafka.admin.AdminClient instead of org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient. Not sure what that first one is exactlybut it is pulling in older methods like the deleteRecordsBefore(). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there any way just to delete one message by giving it offset? thanks